# Реализация БПФ на с++ из Mathcad

Tags: c++, fft

Пытаюсь реализовать БПФ из Mathcad в проекте на Qt c++
[image: формула из Mathcad]
Неполучается интерпретировать данную формулу

ftp://ftp.vt.tpu.ru/distr/MathStat/MathCAD/MathCad%2012/Soft/MathCAD%2012/Mathcad/program%20files/Mathsoft/Mathcad%2012/doc/Help_EN/Help/FFTs_of_real_data.html

Ссылка из документации(первая формула)
С другими действиями все проходило гладко но тут что то не так

```
int NN=1;
while (NN<d) // d - длина исходной выборки, не кратна степени 2
NN*=2;  // обрезка выборки до степени 2

NN/=2;

QVector<double> x6(NN),y6(NN);

for (int j=0; j<NN;j++)
{
double temp=0;

for (int k=0; k<NN;k++)
{
temp+=y5[k]*pow(2.7,-(2*3.14*j*k/NN));
}

y6[j]=temp/sqrt(NN);

}

// y5-массив с исходными значениями
// y6- массив после быстрого преобразования Фурье
// d - длина массива y5 имеет произвольное значение
```

На выходе получается экспоненциальная зависимость, в самой mathcad модели тут совсем другое. Подозревают что не правильно интерпритирую мнимую единицу из формулы, поэтому получается совсем не тот график.

Как мне следует исправить формулу на C++?

Comment: `pow(2.7,-(2*3.14*j*k/NN))` - это вы серьезно? Я уж молчу, что `e^{ix} = cos(x)+i*sin(x)`, но даже использовать `pow(2.7,x)` вместо `exp(x)` - это что-то особенного... Но, отвлекаясь от этого - вообще говоря, насколько вы знакомы с комплексными числами вообще?

Comment: @Harry:  с exp(x) согласен, совсем забыл. Про комплЕксные числа понимаю в теории(мнимая и вещественная часть,все такое, графически как вектор вроде можно представить), но на практике как то туговато, давно изучал (года 4 назад)

Comment: @Harry Расписал как temp+=y5[k]*(qCos(2*pi* j*k/NN)+qSin(i*2*pi* j*k/NN));  где int i=sqrt(-1); - всё равно не  то